# Eclipse Plugin Development: Convert plugin project to maven project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, eclipse-plugin

I have developed an Eclipse plugin project. Now I need to convert it to a Maven Project so that the dependencies etc can be handled using pom.xml.
Is there a way to convert the plugin project to a Maven project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project

you need [eclipse m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) to do this

btw. if you dont know: if you want to use maven with eclipse plugins, you will need tycho too. see [eclipse tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho)